# LaTeX: Citation found in .bib-file but only name of citation returned, bibliography not printed

Tags: latex, bibliography, biblatex

I got this issue in LayteX (Overleaf) where the `\cite{}` and `\textcite{}` command does find my source, but then returns the exact name of the source in my .bib-file. It looks something like this (I couldn't add images somehow):

text...(world'bank"2022)....text.

While the correct output should be:

text... (World Bank, 2022) .... text

The source:

```
@online{world_bank_2022,
    title = {World Bank Open Data {\textbar} Data},
    url = {https://data-worldbank-org.eur.idm.oclc.org/},
    author = {{World Bank}},
    urldate = {2022-10-07},
    date = {2022},
    file = {World Bank Open Data | Data:C\:\\Users\\jhans\\Zotero\\storage\\X739YI3J\\data-worldbank-org.eur.idm.oclc.org.html:text/html},
}
```

The package and file name. Name of the bib-file corresponds 1:1 with the imported library file:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliography-ASP.bib}
```

And as a result, the following command also does not return anything:

```
\newpage
\printbibliography
```

The error messages are:

```
Empty bibliography on input line 360.

Overfull \hbox (6.3094pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 34--35

Citation 'world_bank_2022' on page 1 undefined on input line 34.
```

As an illustration, I created a MWE with the exact same structure and packages as in my original file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs,setspace,caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newtheorem{hyp}{H}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliography IIA ASP.bib}

\title{AS\&P Assignment 3}
\author{Hans van Beek, 497005}
\date{14 October 2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Panel Data Modelling: Time-to-Export}\label{q1}

\subsection{Hypotheses}\label{q1: hypotheses}
The current analysis focuses on three hypothesised determinants of the time-to-export in hours (\textit{time\_to\_export}) between countries and over time using data from the World Bank (\cite{world_bank_2022}). The time-to-export is an important indicator of a country's quality of export and import conditions with a lower time-to-export (\textit{time\_to\_export}) in hours reflecting a more efficient economy. An appropriate determinant of the variation in the size of a country's economy could therefore be the GDP per capita (providing a good benchmark). The first hypothesis (i) therefore states that a higher GDP is

\newpage
\printbibliography

\newpage


\end{document}
```

Comment: Update: when I use `\textcite{}`, I get the error "empty citation". I think the files are connected, but somehow it does not take the content from the .bib-file

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre], so we can check if `\cit()` is just a typo in your question.

Comment: Thanks. I tried doing this just now, and then I DON'T get the issue, which is super annoying. I have no idea what could be wrong with my file. I even used the same packages.

Comment: You can find some tips and strategies for creating a MWE at https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=606

Comment: The point is, that I made it, and that it works. It doesn't work in my complete file. So if you would want to see the issue, you'd have to go over the entire file. I'll update the code above, but that code works. So, that won't help me.

Comment: Make a copy of your complete project and remove stuff so long as the error is still there. This should give you a minimal reproducible example

Comment: I think I did what you requested!

Comment: Your example works fine for me with TL2022 in overleaf https://www.overleaf.com/read/rbfctrnngrxw

Comment: (I wouldn't risk using spaces in file names like your bibliography. This can cause all kinds of problems)